# Fixed points of logical functions

Tags: logic, computer-science, propositional-calculus, fixed-point-theorems

Assume I have a function $F: \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^n$. I would like to analyse the fixed points of such function. This is a difficult problem, determining if there is a fixed point it's NP-complete if I am not mistaken. But I thought it might be doable if I put further restrictions on $F$. For example, I could assume that  $F$ must be represented by a CNF formula with a most $k < n$ literals, or by some other representation with limited expressiveness. Is this something anybody has already worked on? I would be glad for any hints.

Comment: You can't sensibly talk about complexity issues without agreeing on a representation of the problem and you can't agree how to represent the problem if you haven't decided what the problem is. So with the usual representation of an arbitrary function $F : \{0, 1\}^n \to \{0, 1\}^n$ as a list of pairs, the problem of finding a fixed point has polynomial time complexity (and hence is highly unlikely to be NP-complete). How are you planning to represent $F$ using logical formulas?

Comment: If I represent total function of type $F: \{0,1\}^n \to A$ by a list of pairs, the list contains $|\{0,1\}^n| = 2^n$ pairs.  How would you find a fixed point there in polynomial time? I would like to know.

Comment: Complexity is defined in terms of the size of the input under the chosen representation - that is the point of my first comment. That list of $2^n$ pairs represented in the usual way has size $N \ge 2^n$ and the number of steps you need to find a fixed point in it is bounded by a polynomial function of $N$.